# Tmux, change window pane by mouse click

Tags: tmux

Is it possible to use the mouse to navigate between different window panes which are split vertically or horizontally?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

As of [tmux 2.1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmux/tmux/master/CHANGES), 
you can enable this by adding it to your `.tmux.conf`:
`set -g mouse on`

> - Mouse-mode has been rewritten.  There's now no longer options for:
>
>   - mouse-resize-pane
>   - mouse-select-pane
>   - mouse-select-window
>   - mode-mouse
>
>   Instead there is just one option:  'mouse' which turns on mouse
>     support   entirely.

---

See the `mouse-select-pane` option in `man tmux`:

> mouse-select-pane [on | off]
> If on, tmux captures the mouse and when a window is split into multiple panes the mouse may be used to select the current pane.  The mouse click is also passed through to the application as normal.

You can enable this by adding it to your `.tmux.conf`:
`set -g mouse-select-pane on`

Comment: This works great but as I have noticed you loose the ability to select text with mouse or copy mode (`prefix` `Ctrl` + `[`) when you have more than 1 pane.

Comment: Just  saw, that, indeed, I lost the ability to select text with the mouse, but found that I still can select it with SHIFT key being pressed. OpenSuse 12.3, GNOME terminal 3.6.1, tmux 1.7.

Comment: This option doesn't seem to be available in v2.1.

Comment: was happy with this but it seems to have broken `less` pagination so.. nope... I'm on tmux 2.0, may try again with the new setup after upgrading to 2.1

Comment: Can I do this when running tmux over ssh?

Comment: Yes, if your ssh client emulates xterm terminal. So in most cases the answer is yes: it's possible with Windows/Putty, with macos and linux

Comment: I am getting following error message: `.tmux.conf:76: invalid option: mouse-select-pane`

Comment: Using tmux-3.1 here and `set mouse on` works

Comment: In tmux 2.6, this interferes with vim visual selection too. That's a deal breaker!

Comment: If you are using `iTerm` enable clipboard from preferences: `Preferences > General > Selection > Applications in terminal may access clipboard` 
Now no need to press shift, `cmnd+c` works as usual.

Comment: There's a moose on the loose @Patryk

Answer (score 6):

For those who are newbie with tmux, here all the steps to do:

Step 1: Start tmux in your terminal.

```bash
tmux
```

Step 2: Enter tmux's command mode by pressing `Ctrl+b` followed by `:`.

Step 3: Type the following command and press Enter to enable mouse support:

```bash
setw -g mouse on
```

Step 4: You can now use the mouse to click on a window pane to switch to it or click and drag on pane borders to resize them.

Comment: For me this command works ``` set -g mouse on ```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
set-option -g mouse on
bind-key -T root MouseDown1Pane select-pane -t =
```